# GetTemplateChild("CompactOverlayButton") as Button returns Null

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I am creating custom transport controls.

I want to have a Visibility control for a custom Button which I have created. So I have created a Property for it. In that Property, I have used `GetTemplateChild("CompactOverlayButton") as Button` to get the particular button but it returns null.

Here is my code

```
public bool IsCompactOverlayButtonVisible
{
        get
        {
            var compactOverlayButton = GetTemplateChild("CompactOverlayButton") as Button;
            if (compactOverlayButton.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        set
        {
            var compactOverlayButton = GetTemplateChild("CompactOverlayButton") as Button;
            if (value)
                compactOverlayButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            else
                compactOverlayButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
}
```

But the same line of code returns proper value in `OnApplyTemplate()` function.

Here is my code for `OnApplyTemplate()`

```
protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
        var compactOverlayButton = GetTemplateChild("CompactOverlayButton") as Button;
        compactOverlayButton.Click += CompactOverlayButton_ClickAsync;
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IsCompactOverlayButtonVisible` probably gets evaluated for the first time before `OnApplyTemplate()`, meaning that the first time it gets evaluated, the template hasn't been applied and the button doesn't exist yet. In `OnApplyTemplate()`, get the button and assign it to a private field.

```
private Button _compactOverlayButton;
protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    _compactOverlayButton = GetTemplateChild("CompactOverlayButton") as Button;
    _compactOverlayButton.Click += CompactOverlayButton_ClickAsync;
}
```

And before you try to touch the button's properties, make sure it's not null.

```
public bool IsCompactOverlayButtonVisible
{

    get
    {
        return _compactOverlayButton != null
            && _compactOverlayButton.Visibility == Visibility.Visible;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_compactOverlayButton != null)
        {
            compactOverlayButton.Visibility = value 
                                                ? Visibility.Visible
                                                : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

If something will set this value before the template is applied, for example if it's a public property of the control that may be set in XAML (which it sure looks like it is), you can't do it this way. You need to make it a regular dependency property, give it a `PropertyChanged` handler that updates the button's visibility *if* the button exists, and add a line in `OnApplyTemplate()` to update the actual button when you get your hands on it. Then it'll be usable as a target of a binding as well.

## Update

And here's how you do that. This is the right way.

```
private Button _compactOverlayButton;

public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    _compactOverlayButton = GetTemplateChild("CompactOverlayButton") as Button;

    //  Update actual button visibility to match whatever the dependency property value 
    //  is, in case XAML gave us a value for it already. 
    OnIsCompactOverlayButtonVisibleChanged();

    _compactOverlayButton.Click += CompactOverlayButton_Click;

    //  Secondly, just in case something in the XAML may change the button's visibility, 
    //  put a watch on the property and update our dependency property to match when that 
    //  changes. 
    var dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Button.VisibilityProperty, typeof(Button));
    dpd.AddValueChanged(_compactOverlayButton, CompactOverlayButton_VisibilityChanged);
}

protected void CompactOverlayButton_VisibilityChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    IsCompactOverlayButtonVisible = _compactOverlayButton.Visibility == Visibility.Visible;
}

private void CompactOverlayButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //  ...whatever
}

#region IsCompactOverlayButtonVisible Property
public bool IsCompactOverlayButtonVisible
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCompactOverlayButtonVisibleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsCompactOverlayButtonVisibleProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCompactOverlayButtonVisibleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IsCompactOverlayButtonVisible), typeof(bool), typeof(CustomMediaTransportControls),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true,
                                        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                                        IsCompactOverlayButtonVisible_PropertyChanged));

protected static void IsCompactOverlayButtonVisible_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //  It's a hassle to do stuff in a static method, so my dependency property 
    //  snippet just creates a private instance method and calls it from the 
    //  static handler. 
    (d as CustomMediaTransportControls).OnIsCompactOverlayButtonVisibleChanged();
}

private void OnIsCompactOverlayButtonVisibleChanged()
{
    if (_compactOverlayButton != null)
    {
        //  If the existing value is the same as the new value, this is a no-op
        _compactOverlayButton.Visibility = 
            IsCompactOverlayButtonVisible
                ? Visibility.Visible
                : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
#endregion IsCompactOverlayButtonVisible Property
```

Comment: How to give 'PropertyChanged' handler? Can you please update your code with 'PropertyChanged'.

Comment: @VijayNirmal What is the name of your control class that you're working on here?

Comment: 'CustomMediaTransportControls'